# Duplicating the value using echo PHP MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have 2 tables in 1 form I tried echo to duplicate the value of the inputted data. I don't know how to explain but here is the scenario:For example :I have 1 form and it connected to 2 tables. I have 2 input tag (1 date($date1), 1 is hidden($date2)).  So whatever value of the `$date1` it will also the value of the  `$date2`

Here is sample code for this:

```
$date1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date1']);
$date2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['date2']);
// SQL queries like this:
// INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('$date1');
// INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('$date2');
```

```
<form method="POST">
    <input type="date" name="date1" > 
    <input type="hidden" name="date2" value="<?php echo $date1 ?>" >
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

I tried this but value added in database it was blank.

Comment: What is the code that puts data in your database ?

Comment: I don't think there's any problem in `INSERT` I have 3 more input tags there and they actually working. The only problem is that 2 input I can't duplicate the data I inputted in `$date1`

Comment: You want that the `date2` input has the same value as `date1` input ? This has to be done in Javascript clientside not in PHP.

Comment: I see but how? Actually the duplicated input was hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just basic you can use the first `variable` of first insert table for the second insert table.

EDIT:
So here,

```
//first query for your second table 
//if (mysql_query)... here

 $query = "INSERT INTO `Table1` VALUES ('$date1');";

//second query for your second table 
//if (mysql_query)... here

$query = "INSERT INTO `Table2` VALUES ('$date1');";
```

Remove the all variables regarding `$date2` and also the 2nd `input` you don't need that you can duplicate any data by using this kind of coding.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get it.

Comment: Edited, check again my answer

Comment: Will try this sir. wait

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't do it this way. Because when you fill the form, you actually filling the date1 field. date2 field is still empty at the moment. After the POST method, date1 was sent. You can use javascript, so when you enter the date1 field, date2 will be automatically filled.